# locally connected layer on the columns of an input matrix using keras in python

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I have a 3D dataset with dimensions of **[10000, k=5, m=1024]** (10000 is the number of data) and I want to train a network which has a locally connected layer at the first layer. I have shown the first layer in the following image. How can I implement this network using keras in python?

[image]

Comment: what kind of op is this supposed to represent? A dot product between the column k and a row of weights?

Comment: @Lescurel, 
red circle output is:      `Relu ( d_11*w_11 + d_21*w_21 + ... + d_k1*w_k1 )`,
orange circle output is: `Relu ( d_12*w_12 + d_22*w_22 + ... + d_k2*w_k2 )`,
...
blue circle output is:    `Relu ( d_1m*w_1m + d_2m*w_2m + ... + d_km*w_km )`,
k=5 and m=1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem in an easier way. Suppose we have a 3D dataset with dimensions of [10000, 5, 1024]. I have first reshaped it to a matrix in which that for the inputs between 0 to 10000 in the original dataset, I have placed the 5 elements in the columns of the matrix [5, 1024] together, using the following code:

```
mat =  np.reshape(mat,(mat.shape[0],mat.shape[1]*mat.shape[2]),'F')
```

So the `mat` matrix has [10000, 5120] dimensions. Finally I have used the `LocallyConnected1D` predefined layer in tensorflow.keras:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LocallyConnected1D(filters=1, kernel_size=5, strides=5, data_format='channels_first', input_shape=(1,5120), activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation could be this :

```
class LocallyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, k, m, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        # alternatively, you can move that setup in the build method
        # and infer the shape from the input
        # this is left as an exercise to the reader
        self.w = self.add_weight(name="weight", shape=(k,m))
    def call(self, inputs):
        # assuming input has shape [batch, k, m]
        dotp = tf.linalg.diag_part(tf.tensordot(inputs, self.w, axes=[[1],[0]]))
        return tf.nn.relu(dotp)
```

Using `tf.tensordot` to do the dot product over the dimension `k` and extracting only the diagonal, that contains what we want.

A simple example of usage :

```
X = tf.random.normal((100,5,1024))
y = tf.random.normal((100,1))
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input((5,1024)),
        LocallyDenseLayer(5,1024),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
    ]
)
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer="sgd")
model.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lescurel, I will test it and after that I will accept your answer.

Comment: after testing your layer along with 2 dense layers with a distinctive data (2 class of data containing 1 and 5, i.e. 10000*5*1024 values of 1 and 10000*5*1024 values of 5 with labels of 0 and 1 respectively), the accuracy is about 75% which I expected 100% accuracy. Are you sure this layer is correct?

Comment: Just a ran a test with similar data, got 100% accuracy. This does not mean that my code is fullproof though. I did not add a bias in the layer (because your did not request for one), but that might be a good addition.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I first seriously misinterpreted your question, sorry for that. But if I understand correctly, you want to use

[keras.layers.LocallyConnected1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LocallyConnected1D) with kernel_size=1 and dataformat='channels_first'

This would give you a different kernel for every (batch_size, k, 1) tensor.

Comment: Thanks, can you simulate the Lescurel answer with keras.layers.LocallyConnected1D?

Comment: I have used your suggestion about using `keras.layers.LocallyConnected1D` and posted the answer.